# Dirichlet series decomposition of an arbitrary function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, dirichlet-series

Analytic functions can be decomposed into a Taylor series, and furthermore the Taylor series converges back to the original function at every point.

Is there a corresponding notion for Dirichlet series? When is a function able to be decomposed into a Dirichlet series, and does a decomposition exist for any common functions?

Comment: no, you should look at the Laplace transform and then at the Mellin transform to get corresponding theorems for certain classes of functions. (the Dirichlet series being very particular cases of Laplace/Mellin transforms)

Comment: note that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem and this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1791397/on-a-simple-application-of-paley-wiener-theorem-and-related-doubts is very related to the answer we could write with the Mellin/Laplace transform